# Option pricing and mean reversion

Tags: option-pricing, black-scholes, mean-reversion, european-options

In different books one can find a formula for option pricing when we assume that $\ln(S)$ follows a mean reversion process

$$ dS_t/S_t=\kappa(\theta-\ln(S_t))dt+\sigma dZ$$

If we calculate an adjusted volatility

$$\hat{\sigma}=\sigma\sqrt{\frac{1-e^{-2\kappa T}}{2\kappa}}$$

we can use the standard Black-Scholes formula (see for example "The complete guide to option pricing formulas" from Espen Gaarder Haug, page 410).

This has the effect that the price for the option increases with the time to expiry.

But for me there are now two problems:

(1) This is not intuitive because the distribution of the prices in the futures is almost the same if the price is really mean reverting (assume $T \in \{1,2,3\}$)

(2) If I do a Monte Carlo based on a discretization of the stochastic process and calculate the mean of the payout I get the expected result: The option price does not change with time to expiry

How does this fit together?

P.S.: For simplicity we assume that the risk free interest rate $r$ is $0$.

Comment: The futures price at maturity is the same as the underlying spot price. What payout you are calculate the mean? The mean of the option payout is the undiscounted option price, it will certainly depend on the maturity.

Comment: If your option price does not change with time to expiry, then you are doing something wrong in your implementation. As @Gordon mentions the mere fact of discounting should have an impact on the option prices of different maturities.

Comment: @Daneel: We can skip the discounting to makes things as easy as possible.

Comment: @Gordon: Thanks a lot for your details explanation.
Maybe I am doing somewthing wrong, but there is still the same problem: In my eyes the mean reversion makes sure that the standard deviation of the simulated path is always the same (at least at the long end). Is this true or wrong?

Comment: @JoergVanAken: That is true for $S_T$, but not for $(S_T-K)^+$. In addition, your SDE has some typos. Can you make the change?

Comment: @Gordon: Thank you very much for taking the time to help me. I can't see the typos, could you please correct it if necessary? The mean of the simulated paths is always the same, so the standard deviation of $(S_T-K)^+$ does not change either. Since $F(t, T)$ devolves to $\exp(\theta+\sigma^2/(4\kappa)) $ this seems to be right.

Comment: @JoergVanAken: I will make the change for you. It is correct that $f(t, T)$ is close $\exp(\theta+ \sigma^2/(4k))$ as $T$ goes to infinity. But, for the option, we are pricing for a particular $T$.

Comment: @Gordon: Thanks for the edit of the SDE. I guess now I see clearer: my observation does not apply in general. But for certain parameters (e.g.  $\sigma=0.08, \kappa=6, S_0=5, \theta=\log(5.5)$) my observation is right. Right?

Comment: @JoergVanAken: I do not think a particular parameter set will make the option price maturity independent. You may try the option price with your parameters with different maturities.

Answer (score 7):

From the SDE
\begin{align*}
\frac{dS_t}{S_t}= k(\theta-\ln S_t) dt + \sigma dW_t,
\end{align*}
where $\{W_t,\, t\ge 0\}$ is a standard Brownian motion, we obtain that
\begin{align*}
d(e^{kt}\ln S_t) = ke^{kt} \Big(\theta -\frac{1}{2k}\sigma^2\Big) dt + \sigma e^{kt} dW_t.
\end{align*}
Then,
\begin{align*}
\ln S_T = e^{-k(T-t)} \ln S_t + \Big(\theta -\frac{1}{2k}\sigma^2\Big)\Big(1-e^{-k(T-t)} \Big)+\sigma \int_t^T e^{-k(T-s)} dW_s.
\end{align*}
Moreover, for $0 \le t \le T$, the futures price at time $t$ is given by
\begin{align*}
f(t, T) &= E(S_T\,|\, \mathcal{F}_t)\\
&=\exp\bigg(e^{-k(T-t)} \ln S_t + \Big(\theta -\frac{1}{2k}\sigma^2\Big)\Big(1-e^{-k(T-t)} \Big)+ \frac{\sigma^2}{4k} \Big(1-e^{-2k(T-t)} \Big) \bigg).
\end{align*}
Note that, $f(T, T) = S_T$, and
\begin{align*}
df(t, T) &= \sigma e^{-k(T-t)}f(t, T)dW_t,\\
f(0, T) &= \exp\bigg(e^{-kT} \ln S_0 + \Big(\theta -\frac{1}{2k}\sigma^2\Big)\Big(1-e^{-kT} \Big)+ \frac{\sigma^2}{4k} \Big(1-e^{-2kT} \Big) \bigg).
\end{align*}
For $0\le t \le T$, let
\begin{align*}
\sigma_{t,T}^f &= \sqrt{\frac{1}{T-t}\int_t^T \sigma^2 e^{-2k(T-s)} ds}\\
&=\sigma\sqrt{\frac{1-e^{-2k(T-t)}}{2k(T-t)}}.
\end{align*} 
Then, the price, at time $0\le t \le T$, of a European exercise style call option with payoff 
$$(S_T-K)^+,$$ at maturity $T$, is given by
\begin{align*}
e^{-r(T-t)}\big[f(t, T)\Phi(d_1) - K\Phi(d_2) \big],
\end{align*}
where $\Phi$ is the cumulative distribution function of a standard normal random variable, and 
\begin{align*}
d_{1, 2} = \frac{\ln\frac{f(t, T)}{K} \pm \frac{(\sigma_{t,T}^f)^2}{2} (T-t)}{\sigma_{t,T}^f \sqrt{T-t}}.
\end{align*}

Comment: There are a couple of little errors.  The formula for $\sigma_f $ should have  $T-t $ instead of $T $ as we haven't assumed $t=0$.  More seriously in the equation for $d_{1,2} $ both of the $T $ are spurious.  The $\sigma_f $ calculated is the standard deviation of the distribution of $S_T $, not an implied vol.  The implied vol would be divided by $\sqrt {T-t} $.

Comment: @q.t.f.: I am very happy that you have pointed this out. I will make the changes shortly.

Comment: Interestingly, it would appear that for high speeds of mean reversion, the value of the option is independent of the underlying price.  Hence, the option Delta is zero for cases of high speeds of mean reversion.  That is, if $k(T-t)$ is "large," then $f(t,T)$ is effectively independent of $S_t$, therefore $d_1$ and $d_2$ are also effecrively independent of $S_t$, and the value of the option is independent of $S_t$.  Can this possible be the case?

Comment: Well, think about it. With a really high mean reversion and you starting a bit away from your long-term average, your process is just immediately adjusting towards it, wherever it starts. If that effect is very strong, it doesn't really matter where you started, if the mean reversion is barely present, it does still matter where you were.