# Ito's Lemma in option pricing for a stock satisfying $dS=\frac{P-S}{\omega}dt+SdW_t$

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, itos-lemma

Suppose a stock follows the stochastic differential equation

$$dS=\frac{P-S}{\omega}dt+SdW_t,$$

such that $W_t$ is a wiener process, $\omega\in\mathbb{R}^+$, and $P_t,S_t\in\mathbb{R}$. If the value of an option is $V(t,S_t)$, what is the value of $dV(t,S_t)$ given by Itô's Lemma (i.e. similar to the stochastic derivation of the Black-Scholes formula)? Any help would be much appreciated.

So far I have,

$$dV=\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial t}+\frac{P-S}{\omega}\frac{\partial V}{\partial S}+\frac{S^2}{2}\frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial S^2}\right)dt+S\frac{\partial V}{\partial S} dW_t,$$

but I'm not sure whether this is correct or how best to simplify.

Comment: Assuming $P$ is a constant, your expression for $dV$ looks correct to me.

Comment: Thanks for your response. $P$ and $S$ are both functions of $t$, so does this change the expression for $dV$?

Comment: In your expression, $S$ is not a function of $t$ but it is indexed by $t$, yes? In any case, this does not change the expression for $dV$; **unless** $P$ is governed by a stochastic differential equation as well.

Comment: Yes, so $P$ is deterministic and $S$ is indexed by $t$. I assume setting $dV$ to $r\left(V-\frac{\partial f}{\partial S} S\right)dt+\frac{\partial V}{\partial S} dS$ would recover an equation in the form of Black Scholes for risk free rate $r$?

Comment: So you want to calculate the *hedge* portfolio?

Comment: Sure, after finding $dV$ given by Ito's Lemma. Any thoughts on how I might do this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129162/discussion-between-kermittfrog-and-unowen).

Comment: https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/65792/how-to-derive-a-pricing-pde-for-an-asset-that-follows-a-mean-reverting-process this could help you